# Hive View creation issue - Invalid table alias or column reference

Tags: sql, cassandra, hive

Writing this simple view, but its erroring out with below error.
However select query without create view statement works fine

```
    create view test as 
    select  distinct colx from tablex
```

Answer (score 1):

this is not a hive query......